# Javascript Integer with coma and zero at the end

Tags: string, numbers, integer, decimal

How can I append .0 to an integer (300.0) in JavaScript without converting to a string?

```
var wholeNumber = 300.0;
var integer = 300;

console.log( wholeNumber ); //output 300
console.log( parseFloat(wholeNumber) ); //output 300
console.log( parseFloat(integer+".0") ); //output 300
```

I have tried multiple approaches above but seem like isn't working, unless but number comes with decimal like eg 300.1

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```
var a = 300;
console.log(a.toFixed(1));
```

Comment: but if you check using typeof a.toFixed(1), it tells you it is a string